# How to count the proportion of NULL values in the matrix?

Tags: sql, database, dolphindb

Take an example: my metric is like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 7 |
| 2 |  |  |
|  | 6 | 9 |

How to count the proportion of NULL values in the above matrix?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The function [count](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/c/count.html) returns the number of non-null elements in a vector/matrix. And the function [size](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/s/size.html) returns the number of all the elements(NULL value included).

The example script is as follows:

```py
matrix_test = matrix([1 2 NULL, 4 NULL 6], 7 NULL 9)
rate = 1-matrix_test.count()\matrix_test.size()
print(rate)
```

Running result: 0.333333333333333